# msi cannot add shortcut to startup folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, windows-installer

I am using vs2022 to create an msi installation package, and I want to add the program's shortcut to the computer's startup folder during installation.

So during the process of creating the msi installation package, I added the User's Startup Folder in the File System and created a shortcut in it. However, after generating the msi installation package, I tried to install it and could not see this program in the startup folder. shortcut.

What should I do, thanks for anyone's help and advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your steps to create the msi are correct, ShortCut can usually be successfully added to the StartUp folder.

In my attempts, I was able to add ShortCut to the StartUp folder if I opened the installer installer and remembered to click "Everyone", not if you selected "Just me"

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's full of magic!